# Couple questions about logic levels

Tags: microcontroller, logic-level

I have a microcontroller (ATmega328) that runs on 5V and another chip (MAX31855), connected via SPI as a slave (that only using the MISO line), that runs on 3.3V.

1. Do I need to convert the output of the slave from 3.3V to 5V?
2. The chip select pin (active low) is held high via a pullup resistor connected to 3.3V. Is this a problem since it is also connected to the 5V uC? I assume so, yes? Would I need to use a logic level converter for that as well?

Comment: Try it, it should work.
If it is not reliable, then you will want to use a level converter.

Comment: @Matt: Bad advice.  It may *appear* to work, but you have no way to know how much margin there is.  Some other day at a different temperature it might not work.  Worst case is works 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to convert the output of the slave from 3.3V to 5V?

Unlikely because the input logic high acceptable level for the ATmega will probably cover 3.3V devices.

Comment: I haven't looked it up, but I wouldn't be so quick to assume this. Many PICs, for example, have a minimum guaranteed logic high input level of .8 Vdd, which would be 4 V in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this simple 7-step process:

Open datasheet.

Find electrical characteristics section.

Find logic levels section within that.

Find the minimum guaranteed voltage to be interpreted as a high level by the input pin you are using for MISO.

Compare to the 3.3 V the MISO signal will be when high.

If #4 < 3.3V, then it will work, else it won't.

Realize all the above steps should have been obvious.

If the answer is it won't work, then you have to find a solution.  There are many possibilities, one of which is to use a logic level converter.